# Could not find module 'TLSphinx' for architecture 'arm64'; found: i386

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am using the [TLSphinx from GitHub](https://github.com/tryolabs/TLSphinx) with my Xcode Swift iOS Project. I had built the TLSphinx project before I used the framework.

I had been given incomplete and confusing instructions from [spinxbase on GitHub](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase), [pocketsphinx](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx), and [pocketspinx-ios-demo](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-ios-demo). It's not clear what those have to do with TLSphinx. I didn't alter TLSphinx in any way to use those other sources. I have filed issues with the appropriate repositories.

At the import statement for TLSphinx in my Swift file in my project, I get this error:

> Could not find module 'TLSphinx' for architecture 'arm64'; found: i386

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending how you are building "TLSphinx" framework, this error basically means that the framework was built for iOS simulator 32-bits, not for iPhone devices, which require arm64 architecture.

To remedy this, I suggest you use Carthage as the repo seems to support it. If you don't want to fully integrate Carthage with your project, the very least amount of steps you need to take are:

1. Create a temp directory somewhere, say `mkdir foo && cd foo`
2. Create Cartfile with the following line: `github "Tryolabs/TLSphinx"`
3. Run `carthage update --platform iOS`
4. Drag `Carthage/Build/iOS/TLSphinx` into your project
5. Update `framework search paths` in your project settings to where the framework is
6. Build, run.

Once you are prepared to ship to the AppStore, make sure to learn more about Carthage, and use `copy-framework` command to strip simulator slices.